# Setting exception message to an array

Tags: php, exception

I created a class `MyException` that extends `Exception` and in its constructor I wrote:   `$this->message = array("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B")`.
After, when I called `getMessage()` I got the array as expected.
A while after I started getting the message as the string "Array". When in look in debug mode I saw that before throwing the `exception` the message is still good but inside the `catch` it suddenly only shows the string "Array".
When I read about it I started questioned how in fact it worked in the first place because it sounds like you cannot place an `array` as the message but I swear to god that it worked.
I know I can set the array in a different field but I want to use `getMessage()` so I could work the same with `MyException` as with the regular `Exception`.

EDIT:
Here is an example to make the problem clearer:

```
        $ex = new MyException("SomeValue", "AnotherValue");
        echo "Before: ";
        print_r($ex->getMessage());
        echo "\n";
        try
        {
            throw $ex;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "After: ";
            print_r($ex->getMessage());
            echo"\n";
        }
```

Output:

```
Before: Array(
[a] => SomeValue
[b] => AnotherValue)
After: Array
```

EDIT #2:
I figured it out. To activate the debugger I placed xdebug.so on the device. If I remove it everything is fine. Why? who knows..

Comment: Might be cause you were `echoing`  an array instead if `print_r` and you were suppressing `notice` too

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, with `print_r` ofcourse:

```
<?php 
class MyException extends Exception {       
    public function __construct($a, $b) { 
        $this->message = array("a" => $a, "b" => $b);
    } 
}

$ex = new MyException("SomeValue", "AnotherValue");
echo "Before: ";
print_r($ex->getMessage());
echo "\n";
try
{
    throw $ex;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "After: ";
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
    echo"\n";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it still doesn't work. Between the throw and the catch the array becomes just the string "Array" and that's what is printed. I edited my post to make it clear

Comment: I edited my post, that outputs: `Before: Array ( [a] => SomeValue [b] => AnotherValue ) After: Array ( [a] => SomeValue [b] => AnotherValue )`